# :before pseudo class not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

At [this page](http://dev.uniscope.com.au/plans/), I'd like to add some text above the gray box containing "ADSL Broadband 1".

[image]

I've tried using the following CSS rule, but it isn't working:

```
.vc_tta-panels #adsl .vc_tta-panel-body:before {
    content: 'text goes here';
}
```

Can you see what is wrong here, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your other rules override this rule, you should add [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property, for example:

```
.vc_tta-panels #adsl .vc_tta-panel-body:before {
    content: 'text goes here';
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I can't get the text to display before the dark grey box. I've tried `.vc_tta-panels #adsl .vc_tta-panel-body:before { content: 'text goes here'; display: block; line-height: 1.2; width: auto; height: auto; margin-bottom: 1em; }`

Comment: @Steve you could add `margin-top: -15px` for example.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written is working fine, but at the same time, it's getting hidden by your `CSS` written at some other place.

```
   vc_tta-panels #adsl .vc_tta-panel-body:before {
     content: 'Hello';
     display: block !important;
   }
```

Attaching a snapshot of issue, from where it gets hidden due to `display:none` given.
[image]

Comment: I can't get the text to display before the dark grey box. I've tried `.vc_tta-panels #adsl .vc_tta-panel-body:before {
 content: 'text goes here';
 display: block;
 line-height: 1.2;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}`